# Balance sheets & bad debt accounts

Tags: accounting, financial-statements

I have a confusion as to whether bad debt accounts are factored into the accounts receivable of a company's balance sheet?

To clarify/illustrate my question,

If a company is expecting $3000 in future payments for services it has provided, but estimates that $1000 of this sum will never be paid, will the amount listed under accounts receivable on the balance sheet be $3000 or $2000?

Also, is this method standard/uniform in every country?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only when you actually write off the bad debt should your accounts receivable go down. There are rules for this under GAAP (Generally Accepted Accounting Principles).

For a more elaborate explanation look here:
http://smallbusiness.chron.com/gaap-rules-bad-debt-42598.html
http://accountingexplained.com/financial/receivables/bad-debts